# How to specify the number of partitions reading parquet into a Dask dataframe?

Tags: dask, dask-delayed

I read my parquet data as follows:

```
file_names = glob.glob('./events/*/*/*/*/*/part*.parquet')
pf = fp.ParquetFile(file_names, root='./events')
pf.cats = {'customer': pf.cats['customer']}
dfs = (delayed(pf.read_row_group_file)(rg, pf.columns, pf.cats) for rg in pf.row_groups)
df = dd.from_delayed(dfs)
```

I can't use `dd.read_parquet`, because my parquet is partitioned, and I want to avoid loading some of the categoricals.

I have two questions here:

- How can I tell Dask what number of partitions I want my dataframe to have?
- How many partitions will Dask create by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I suspect that the `dd.read_parquet` function works fine with partitioned or multi-file parquet datasets.

Second, if you are using `dd.from_delayed`, then each delayed call results in one partition.  So in this case you have as many partitions as you have elements of the `dfs` iterator.  If you wish to change this you can call the `repartition` method afterwards.